# merge list of dictionaries which have list init

Tags: python, python-2.7

My current list:

```
my_list = [
   {'id': 1, 'val': [6]},
   {'id': 2, 'val': [7]},
   {'id': 3, 'val': [8]},
   {'id': 2, 'val': [9]},
   {'id': 1, 'val': [10]},
]
```

Desired output:

```
my_list = [
   {'id': 1, 'val': [6, 10]},
   {'id': 2, 'val': [7, 9]},
   {'id': 3, 'val': [8]},
]
```

what I tried so far:

```
    my_new_list = []
    id_set = set()

    for d in my_list:
        if d['id'] not in id_set:
            id_set.add(d['id'])
            temp = {'id': d['id'], 'val': d['val']}
            my_new_list.append(temp)
        else:
             # loop over the new list and find the dict which already have d['id'] and update by appending value
             # but this is not efficient
```

any other more efficient approach or may be some inbuilt function I'm not aware of.

PS: Order is important!

Comment: Given the new list will have a unique value for `id`, you can use a dictionary instead, with `id` as a key. This way you don't have to loop over the new list, you can access it by id directly.

Comment: Is the order of the output list important?

Comment: @schwobaseggl: yes order is important thats why I didn't use dictionary as mentioned y spectras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is your friend:

*(We should use `collections.OrderedDict` to remember the order that keys were first inserted.)*

```
>>> import collections

>>> result = collections.OrderedDict()
>>> for d in my_list:
...     result.setdefault(d["id"], []).extend(d["val"])

>>> lst = []
>>> for k, v in result.items():
...     lst.append({"id": k, "val": v})
```

Comment: The list comprehension form of the second part is pretty readable as well`lst = [{"id": k, "val": v} for k, v in result.items()]`

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as [ozgur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793428/ozgur), but using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for dd in my_list:
        d[dd['id']].extend(dd['val'])
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [6, 10], 2: [7, 9], 3: [8]})
>>>
>>> lst = []
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
        lst.append({'id':k, 'val':v})

>>> lst
[{'id': 1, 'val': [6, 10]}, {'id': 2, 'val': [7, 9]}, {'id': 3, 'val': [8]}]
>>>
```

Comment: order is important for me. can we do it using `OrderedDict` instead of `defaultdict`.

Comment: If order from your original `my_list`, then it is keeping order, as it is iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in order to sort and group the original `list` by `'id'` and accumulate the `'val'` for each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

key_fnc = lambda d: d['id']
result = [
    {'id': k, 'val': sum([d['val'] for d in g], [])} 
        for k, g in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=key_fnc), key=key_fnc)
]
```